# cell.accessoryType not workinkg in tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath... method

Tags: objective-c, tableview, accessorytype

I have a tableView inside a Navigation Controller

I want to change the background and I use

```
[[self view] setBackgroundColor:SomeColor];
```

in the `-awakeFromNib` method in the controller class

if "SomeColor" is black I cannot see the `cell.accessoryType (UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator)`.

is there a way to make it white?

I try to set `cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;` in the `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` metod but nothing happens, am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe provide more code. Changing the color shouldnt affect the cell accessories.

Comment: `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is the proper place to set up the cell, and since the disclosure arrow is gray, it should still be visible even if the background of the cell is black.  Also, please note that the disclosure button is a **button**, and not just another type of arrow.  It is meant to cause a different action when tapped directly, versus tapping the cell in general.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do it in `- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {`
if the table view is plained.